# compileOnly() Couldn't Be Found In A Multi-module Setting

Tags: gradle

In a multi-module Gradle project, all sub-projects are flat and they don't have any dependencies on others. In the base project directory, the settings.gradle file has the following content:

```
rootProject.name = 'base-project'
include 'server-1', 'server-2', 'server-3', 'business-app', 'gateway'
```

When I run "./gradlew build" on the base project directory, I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':business-app'.
> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [org.projectlombok:lombok] on project ':business-app'.
```

For a dependency entry in the project's build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
  ...
}
```

The error doesn't occur if I run the same build command in the project directory.

I can't find any helpful information online. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `compileOnly` configuration is added to the build context by applying the java plugin. likely you don't have

```
apply plugin:'java'
```

for your subproject defined. Adding it should solve that issue.

Comment: The build.gradle file of the subproject does have the line. If it were indeed the cause, how to explain the build command running fine in the subproject directory?

Comment: weird. which gradle version do you use?

Comment: I don't have access to the PC at this moment. I believe the Gradle version is 4.x. I know some reports of similar problem for 2.x.

Comment: Applying it to root build.gradle solved my problem. Thanks!